# Android touch: How does one detect if a view on a screen is completely covered by a finger?

Tags: android, touch-event

Say I have a 5dp x 5dp view on the Android touch screen that I ask the user to touch, how do I detect that the user is completely covering the view with the finger when the user touches it?

Comment: What if the user wants to use a stylus? What if the user is using assistive technologies and is not using a finger to interact with your UI?

Comment: Thanks for the response, for this use case they have to use a finger

Comment: How would you prevent them from using a stylus if they wanted to? This doesn't seem possible, and I don't think this information is available. What if the user has big fingers but there is only a small point of contact with the screen?

Comment: This use case will need a finger to be placed and nothing else. The user using the app knows that using any other tool will not make sense for the usecase